# how to run multiple websites and serve different content in django 1.6?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to start one project of django and ideally it will have one admin panel . 
I want to point different domains and subdomains (subdomains on more priority) and want to serve different content and pages when some1 hit my server .

So to be in details if i have two domains : 
1) abc.com
2) xyz.com 
Then if someone put abc.com then i should be able to see page1 and all urls associated with this abc.com should be available and should be able to see page2 when someone use xyz.com

and xyz.com/new/ should deliver different content and abc.com/new/ should give different content .

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) for this . It is very strong CMS framework build into django.
To implement multisite application you can use [djagno multisite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multisite/0.3.1)  app . It is very easy to integrate .

Answer (score 0):

With the [site framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) linked into your models, you can associate data to different sites.

You can also use it in your views like in the example taken from the official doc:

from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

```
def my_view(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    if current_site.domain == 'foo.com':
        # Do something
        pass
    else:
        # Do something else.
        pass
```